# failed to call cssClass through jquery when working with spring mvc tab and apache tiles

Tags: jquery, css, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am using spring mvc 3 with apache tiles 3. I have implemented a "nested tabs" concept with apache tiles.

Everything is working fine except that the currently active tab is not getting highlighted.

*I want to highlight the current active tab using css and jquery when tab is clicked.*

Thanks in advance.

here is the jsp for nested tabs.
when i locally used jqueryui.js the tabs r working fine and getting highlighted.
when  i am using spring mvc a new page in the browser is opened whenever i click on a tab.
But what i am trying is whenever i click on a tab the control should go to a controller and return the same jsp page with clicked tab highlighted.

for this i used apache-tiles to design tabs using templates and i am getting tabs as well as their respective jsp pages but the tab on which **I CLICK IS NOT GETTING HIGHLIGHTED**

Below is the code for the main template.jsp

template.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Template 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
</body>
</html>
```

In its header i load a tabs.jsp page which has code for the tabs.

here is tabs.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>System SetUp Tab</title>
<script  src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.js"/> "></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap1.1.css"/>">
<%-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery-ui.css"/>"> --%>

<style type="text/css">

 CSS FOR TABS WHICH IS WORKING FINE

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 4px;">
<div id="mytab" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all " style="border: none;">
    <ul class="tabs ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="border-left:none;border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;margin-right: -1px;">

    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><spring:url value="/aa" var="aa" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="${aa}">A</a></li>

    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><spring:url value="/bb" var="bb" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <a  class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="${bb}">b</a></li>

    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><spring:url value="/cc" var="cc" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="${cc}">c</a></li>

    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top "><spring:url value="/dd" var="dd" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <a  class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="${dd}">d</a></li>

    <li class="liname" title="Parameter Setup" style="color: blue;float:right;border:none;background: none;">PS-1.0</li>
  </ul>

</div>

   </div>
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
('#mytab').tabs();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

inside "body" of template.jsp i load jsp pages of tabs based on the tab clicked.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @gjhuizing I have edited my question n added the code required to understand my question.check out if u can give me some idea